# Entity data in crudcontroller based on current logged in user or user id

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, symfony5, easyadmin

I'm new to Symfony and I've already learned a lot, but now I run into a problem that I can't find the answer to.

I have a crudcontroller which uses the entity (e.g.) Articles, but the articles in the database have different user ids.

The crudcontroler MUST only show the articles of the current logged in user/user id.  I know how to get the user id, but I don't know how to manipulate the entity to ONLY get the articles for the specific user to display in the crudcontroller.

Example:
User with user id 5 is logged in the dashboard. Get articles where user id is 5 in crudcontroller ONLY. Do not get or display any other.

Symfony version: 5.2
Easyadmin: 3.2

I hope someone can push me in the right direction. Currently pulling my hair out on this one. Nothing to be found on Google on this subject.

EDIT:

I've finally found the way to have more control with the createIndexQueryBuilder().
I've overridden that one with:

```
    public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
{
    $response = parent::createIndexQueryBuilder($searchDto,$entityDto,$fields,$filters);
    $response->where('entity.user_id = 5);
    return $response;
}
```

BUT then I get this error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 65 near 'user_id = 5': Error: Class App\Entity\RepairServices has no field or association named user_id

That's right because user_id isn't part of the entity BUT it is in the database and I need to check on it. How can I do that?

Comment: filter broke after that how to fix ?